# XPath find node coontaining node name

Tags: xml, xpath

Lets say I have the following XML.

```
<Table>
    <Row1>
        <Name>My Name</Name>
        <LastName>LastName</LastName>
    </Row1>
    <Row2>
        <Name>My Name2</Name>
        <LastName>LastName2</LastName>
    </Row2>
</Table>
```

I understand that this is poor layout by I cant change that unfortunately. So, I want to find all the `Nodes` containing `'Row'`

I have tried this expression but it doesnt seem to work unfortunately:
`//Table//*[contains(.,'Row')]`

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*[contains(.,'Row')]
```

checks for elements whose *value* contains the substring `Row` - if you want elements whose *name* contains that string then instead you need

```
*[contains(name(),'Row')]
```

or if you want to be more specific

```
*[starts-with(local-name(),'Row')]
```

to find just `Row1`, `Row2`, `RowFoo`, etc. but not `AnotherRow`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(),'Row')]
```

like Ian suggested.

Or better

```
//Table/*[starts-with(local-name(),'Row')]
```